# Formatting keywords within Text using Sanity

Tags: css, reactjs, sanity

I am trying to create a testimonial section for my website. I use Sanity to manage all of my content so I can edit it easily. What I would like to do is have keywords highlighted in the testimonial like in the image below. However, using the Sanity 'text' type I am not sure how to do this.

Any suggestions?[image]